# ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package Intra-package References

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.8, python-3.9

I'm getting "ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package" error while running main.py. Below is my folder structure. Please help me i'm confused. Also, tried this article https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html **"6.4.2. Intra-package References"**

```
test(folder) which has below files
   |--> __init__.py
   |--> a.py
   |--> b.py
   |--> main.py
```

**a.py**

```
def test():
    print('hi')
```

**b.py**

```
def testing():
    print('helo')
```

**main.py**

```
from . import a,b

a.test()
b.testing()
```

**Error:**

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 1, in 
from . import a,b
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package

Comment: isn't `import a` working?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you want that?

Comment: (https://realpython.com/absolute-vs-relative-python-imports/) please check this out...